# iphone development: using touch down and touch up inside simultaneosly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interaction

In my app I use a button and I assign two methods to them one is working when you touch down( the button image is changed), the other is working when you touch up inside (another view is opened). so simply, if you want to open a view you press the button but when you touch the button the image is changed and after you raise up your finger the another view is opened. My problem is if you press the button the image is changed, however if you move your finger somewhere away from the button touch up inside is not working as it supposed to be. But the problem is the image sticks with its over version because touch down is triggered once. what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this in the control states `touchDragOutside` or `touchDragExit` depending on exactly what you want it to do. Using `touchDragOutside` you can detect when the user touches down inside the button and drags their finger away without leaving the touchable bounds of the button, and `touchDragExit` detects when they drag outside the buttons touchable bounds.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
```

Answer (score 2):

I do recommend you to use this method of the UIButton Object to change the images.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

You could see all the options for the state in here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

I would used the states UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateHighlighted for your target.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem myself, and mostly we use these events:-

// This event works fine and fires

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(holdDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

// This does not fire at all

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(holdRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

**Solution:-**

Use Long Press Gesture Recognizer:-

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *btn_LongPress_gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleBtnLongPressgesture:)];
[button addGestureRecognizer:btn_LongPress_gesture];
```

Implementation of gesture:-

```
- (void)handleBtnLongPressgesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{


//as you hold the button this would fire

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    [self someMethod];
}

//as you release the button this would fire

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    [self someMethod];
}
}
```